# Crazy! Angular 1.6 + video.js, videoJS must be initialized with a setTimeout(0)

Tags: angularjs, video.js

These codes have a bug that videoJS can't be initialized with ng-src.

```
$scope.showVideo = function (videoLink) {
    $scope.videoLink = videoLink;
    $('#video').modal('show');
    var updateSrc = $rootScope.videoDomain('teacher') + videoLink;
    if (ctrl.videoPlayer) {
        ctrl.videoPlayer.src(updateSrc);
        ctrl.videoPlayer.load(updateSrc);
    } else {
         ctrl.videoPlayer = videojs('#VideoTeacher', {
              html5: {nativeTextTracks: false}
         });
    }
    $('#video').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $(this).find('video')[0].pause();
    });
};
```

OK! I thought that it might be the problem about sequence.
But after I add a setTimout(0) function outside, it works! See codes below.
May I know, why? And It's any proper way to solve this problem?

```
    setTimeout(function () {
        ctrl.videoPlayer = videojs('#VideoTeacher', {
            html5: {nativeTextTracks: false}
        });
    }, 0);
```

Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

I see some jQuery in your code. Angular has no knowledge of jQuery events. Angular only knows when it needs to update based on async calls. These include ajax requests (via `$http`), and timeouts.

We have no idea what your markup looks like, but it's likely that you (or Videojs) are expecting Angular to pick up on a change that it has no knowledge of. This tends to happen when you mix jQuery and Angular. `setTimeout` works because it is an async call which triggers Angular to check for changes.

See these articles about why `setTimeout` seems to "fix things":
https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/
http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html